# conditional with answer on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

We need to fill a cell based on two other cells values. Something like:

```
=IF(AND(A1="High",B1="Green"),"Sheet3 A1")
```

In this example I am using Sheet3 to hold the values to be plug in (on sheet3 `A1 ="HighPriority"`).  Obviously, the way this statement currently works is that it just plugs in the words `"Sheet3 A1"`....   Also, if it is possible to plug in the correct value then we also need to carry over the color of that cell on Sheet3...   This report is for high level executive and would be so great if we could make this happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes around the sheet name, exclamation point between sheet name and cell reference:

> `=IF(AND(A1="High",B1="Green"),'Sheet3'!A1,"")`

You also need those last empty quotation marks, or whatever you want to display when the `IF` is false.